# Unable to start service com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService@3399b37 with null

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-play-services, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I am receiving these crash reports from my crash reporting tools.
I don't which code to provide here so just let me know if you want to see any particular code.

I haven't put anything related to GoogleAnalytics in onStart method as it is not mentioned in documentation.

> Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException Unable to start service
>   com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService@3399b37 with null:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object
>   reference
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service
>   com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService@3399b37 with null:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null object
>   reference
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2910)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:147)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'java.lang.String android.content.Intent.getAction()' on a null
>   object reference
>          at com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService.onStartCommand()
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2893)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:147)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
>          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
>          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
>          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)

Answer (score 4):

This is a reported bug with the Google Analytics: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=667.

Comment: This bug is long due and haven't been addressed in API 7.8 as well. :-/

Comment: TL;DR - as for June 2016, this bug seems to be fixed since play-services-analytics version 9.0.2